# Azure active directory - Get access token using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

My objective is to get access token for a user for a resource( an AD app present in the tenant)

I have been able to get access token for a service principal by using

az login --service-principal -u  -p  --tenant  --allow-no-subscriptions

az account get-access-token --resource

Now when I try to achieve the same for a user by switching service-principal login by user login(az login)

az login

az account get-access-token --resource

This however gives an error

Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'abc'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 19fdf309-f9ef-423b-8c18-7cd9269b0700\r\nr\nTimestamp: 2019-11-21 09:03:25Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2019-11-21 09:03:25Z","trace_id":"19fdf309-f9ef-423b-8c18-7cd9269b0700","correlation_id":"2aafc4e4-0c1b-42b3-ba59-afe09bbe9fb5","suberror":"consent_required"}

Can someone help me understand why this is the case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to get token from `<APP ID Uri>` using Azure CLI, which client ID is exactly `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46`.

[image]

Go to the resource(App in AD)->Expose an API->Add client application with `04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46` and check scope.

[image]

Then get the access token again.

[image]

Comment: but why does the same work in the context of an AD app?

Comment: @user3740951 The ways to get access token between sp and user are different.

Comment: Can we also identify the user who requested the token with this solution? For example if the resource is an app service, configured with the particular app registration.